# How to connect Constrain Layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm going to create a adaptive android Activity for both mode Portal and Landscape screen as bellow

- ConstraintLayout for content (the blue light background color), with        android:id="@+id/contentAct"
- FrameLayout for google ads area, with     android:id="@+id/frameLayout_googleads"

All them put in one ConstraintLayout, with   android:id="@+id/mainAct"

This is my expectation layout

Portal:

[image]

Landscape:
[image]

I'm using ConstraintSet to connect that layouts together

this is my source:

```java
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainAct);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

int nIdRoot = R.id.mainAct;
int nIdAds = R.id.frameLayout_googleads;
int nIdContent = R.id.contentAct;
if(nOrientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    Log.d("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");
    //for ads
    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdAds,ConstraintSet.TOP,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    //constraintSet.connect(R.id.frameLayout_googleads,ConstraintSet.LEFT,R.id.mainAct,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdAds,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdAds,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

    constraintSet.setVerticalBias(nIdAds, 0.5f);
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(nIdAds, 1.0f);



    //for content
    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.TOP,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.LEFT,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);



    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,nIdAds,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);

    constraintSet.setVerticalBias(nIdContent, 0.5f);
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(nIdContent, 0.0f);


}
else{
    Log.d("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");

    //for ads
    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    //constraintSet.connect(R.id.frameLayout_googleads,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.mainAct,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdAds,ConstraintSet.LEFT,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdAds,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdAds, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdAds,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

    constraintSet.setVerticalBias(nIdAds, 1.0f);
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(nIdAds, 0.5f);

    //for content
    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.TOP,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.LEFT,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,nIdAds,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);

    constraintSet.clear(nIdContent, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.connect(nIdContent,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,nIdRoot,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);

    constraintSet.setVerticalBias(nIdContent, 0.0f);
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(nIdContent, 0.5f);
}
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

It looks like working fine for Portal mode,
but in Landscape mode, the Right of Content Layout connected to Right Of Root layout, It should be connected to the Left of Ads layout.

[image]

It canbe fix by manual adjust the width of ContentLayout for lanscape mode as bellow,

```java
//begin adjust content width step
View viewcontentAds = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout_googleads);
View viewcontentAct = findViewById(R.id.contentAct);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParamsAds = viewcontentAds.getLayoutParams();
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParamsContent = viewcontentAct.getLayoutParams();

int nNewContentWidthPx = 0;
if(nOrientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    nNewContentWidthPx = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - layoutParamsAds.width;
}
else{
    nNewContentWidthPx = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
layoutParamsContent.width = nNewContentWidthPx;
//begin adjust content width step
```

But How can I correct the width of ContentLayout without manual adjust it.

this is the full template runable source code
https://github.com/minhnv16/TestAdsMultiAct/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/testadsmultiact/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're following is discouraged. In fact, Android provides alternative resource folder for both landscape and portrait mode.

You should create your layout for landscape mode in the `res/layout-land` folder whereas `res/layout-port` for the portrait one.

With that, you don't need to dynamically adjust the constraints set.